# T4 Code Transformations using C#

Tags: c#, wcf, t4, transformation

In short, I am currently working on a research problem for my university that focuses on Model Transformations for service oriented solutions based on an Analysis and Design Methodology. After a meta-model has been gathered, my job is to transform this requirements into a workable and deploy-able WCF Component Service Library. So far I have been successful with transforming all required objects into C# code using Pre-Processed Text Templates, however my questions are:

- How can I group all generated files together with a build-able project file (*.csproj). I don't want the user to have to create a new project and add the generated files manually. Instead one should be automatically generated with all files included and assemly references added and the user should be able to open the project from a location on disk.
- What will be the best approach to go about or manage assembly references and how will i be able to include them during runtime? I.e. to mark an Interface with [`ServiceContract`] attribute I would firstly need to add Systems.ServiceModel as reference to the project and secondly include it in the module. How can this be done?
- Lastly how to generate the web.config configuration file to define service behaviors, endpoint addresses, bindings or any other needed settings. I don't feel T4 templates is the right approach for this.

Any recommendations or guidance on the above stated problems will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since the web config and project definitions are XML you may want to use XSLT

Comment: Afaik, service behaviors don't need to be added to the web config, they can be done programmatically.  (Please note, this is only third hand knowledge, I've never set this up myself, just read it somewhere (likely here)).

Comment: Your best bed might be to create a project file by hand, then strip out everything relating to files you want to add and turn what's left into a template.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the tooling does everything you want to do.  You'd just have to figure out how and repurpose for your needs.

Comment: Yeah I am also pretty certain that this functionality is already provided, the problem is I have not discovered it, nor how to use it to satisfy this requirement hence my reason to ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, I was able to accomplish this by using Predefined project templates with assembly references and a default web.config already included. After my transformations have been completed, i will update the appropriate sections in the web.config with details relevant to the transformed service.

```
DTE2 dte2 = (DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");
Solution2 soln = (Solution2)dte2.Solution;

string templateFileLoc = soln.GetProjectTemplate("My Pre-defined project template", "csproj");

soln.AddFromTemplate(templateFileLoc, outputDir, projectName, false);

var proj = soln.Projects.Item(soln.Projects.Count);

proj.ProjectItems.AddFromFileCopy(generatedFile);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you found.